# Why Does Python Script Jump Over Some Entries And Not Others?

Tags: python

In a Python list, an entry I expected to be removed remained, and another entry was removed. Why is that?

Here's the problematic code:

```
def getAdjacent(pos, bounds):
    posibles = [
    [pos[0]-1, pos[1]],
    [pos[0]+1, pos[1]],
    [pos[0], pos[1]-1],
    [pos[0], pos[1]+1]]
    for p in posibles:
        if isOutside(p,bounds):
            posibles.remove(p)
    return posibles


def isOutside(pos, bounds):
    if pos[0] > bounds[0]-1 or pos[0] < 0 or pos[1] < 0 or pos[1] > bounds[1]-1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Here's some Inputs and outputs that reflect the problem:

```
In [13]: bounds = [10, 10]

In [14]: p = [9,0]

In [15]: getAdjacent(p, bounds)
Out[15]: [[8, 0], [9, -1], [9, 1]]

In [16]: isOutside([9, -1], bounds)
Out[16]: True

In [17]: isOutside([9, 1], bounds)
Out[17]: False
```

Now why is [9, -1] still in getAdjacent() when getAdjacent() removes all elements that cause isOutside() to retrun True? And why isn't [10, 0] still in there? Is it a magnitude thing?

Answer (score 8):

Don't remove elements from lists you're iterating over:

```
for p in posibles:
    if isOutside(p,bounds):
        posibles.remove(p)
```

This confuses the iteration and results in skipped entries.  I'd write this as

```
possibles = [p for p in possibles if not isOutside(p, bounds)]
```

Comment: ah, i see :). thanks allot (and thanks for the spelling correction too :) )